# please translate, ‘forward, always forward’. and ‘what’s behind us is behind us’. thanks

Tags: idiom

Would you please translate the following?

‘forward, always forward’ and ‘what’s behind us is behind us’.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jim! I recommend separating your two translation requests into two different questions. This site is most useful when a question contains a single question (or the multiple questions are very closely related).

Comment: I have put your question on hold. If you edit it to elaborate on the context (e.g. if you planned to use these phrases together somehow) or to ask for the two translations separately, I will be happy to reopen the question. Explaining the context always helps you get a more appropriate translation.